# Method to build a new Linked List with the odd numbered elements from a given Linked List

Tags: java

//This code does not work. I dont know what I am doing wrong. Its a doubly linked list, and the hint is to use the list iterator.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ExtLinkedList<E> extends LinkedList<E>
{

    public ExtLinkedList<E> oddItemsList () 
    {
        ExtLinkedList<E> oddList = new ExtLinkedList<E>();
        ListIterator<E> itr = oddList.listIterator();
        for(int i = 0; itr.hasNext(); i++)
        {
            //E element = itr.next();
            if(i % 2 == 1)
            {
                //System.out.print(element);
                itr.remove();
                itr.next();
            }
            i++;
        }
        return oddList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your "given LinkedList"?

Comment: The problem states that since it extends the linked list class in java. You can first use that to make a new linked list and from that linked list build a new linked list

Comment: Try this: `ListIterator<E> itr = listIterator();` instead of `ListIterator<E> itr = oddList.listIterator();` to get the iterator of your already existing list. Otherwise you are getting the iterator of a new list which contains no elements.

Comment: The first and last pointer points to null

Comment: The returned list that is. WHen i use the object bench in Blue J to inspect the pointers. The first and last are pointing to null. The linked does have elements, but after calling this method, the returned list shows nothing.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to remove your extra i++ at the end. The for loop already has i++ so you don't need to have another one at the bottom. You could have easily discovered that by stepping through the code with a debugger.

Comment: Yes, I did that but still shows the same result. Maybe we need to reassign the pointers after we create a new LinkedList and add elements in it.

Comment: Nope, you must be doing something wrong. I tested the code below and it works.

Comment: How did you test it? I added elements to the linked list and then called this method. And then I used the Blue J object bench to inspect it.

Comment: I did the same. Double-check your code and the code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really a Java developer but this should work better:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ExtLinkedList<E> extends LinkedList<E>
{

    public ExtLinkedList<E> oddItemsList () 
    {
        ExtLinkedList<E> oddList = new ExtLinkedList<E>();

        //Get the iterator of the current list instead of the new empty list.
        //Otherwise you will iterate over nothing.
        ListIterator<E> itr = listIterator();

        for(int i = 0; itr.hasNext(); i++)
        {
            E element = itr.next();
            if(i % 2 == 1)
            {
                //System.out.print(element);
                oddList.add(element);
            }
        }
        return oddList;
    }
}
```

Modifications:

1. Call listIterator() on the current list instead of on the empty oddList.
2. You don't need to remove the elements as you go because this would alter your original list.
3. Add the element returned by next() to your oddList

Comment: The returned list that is. WHen i use the object bench in Blue J to inspect the pointers. The first and last are pointing to null. The linked does have elements, but after calling this method, the returned list shows nothing.